# TypeError: Error #1006: addChild is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to embed a "pre-made" flash actionscript 3 gallery into my own flash animation. Both animations work in good ways independently. But once I insert the photo gallery into my own project I am getting an error of;

```
TypeError: Error #1006: addChild is not a function.
at project_fla::galeri_6/onCompleteXmlLoad()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

My flash button code which leads to gallery is;

```
stop();

galeri_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, galeri);

function galeri(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

And lastly, the flash gallery code is;

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;


var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("photo_gallery.xml"));

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteXmlLoad);

var xmlFile:XML;


var xcoord:int = 10;

var gal:gallery = new gallery();
gal.x = 10;
gal.y = 10;
addChild(gal);

var thumbsContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
thumbsContainer.x = 10;
thumbsContainer.y = 320;
addChild(thumbsContainer);


var txtTitle:TextField = new TextField();
txtTitle.x = 15;
txtTitle.y = 15;
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.bold = true;
format.color = 0xFFFFFF;
format.size = "20";
format.font = "Arial";
txtTitle.defaultTextFormat = format;
addChild(txtTitle);

var txtDesc:TextField = new TextField();
txtDesc.x = 15;
txtDesc.y = 40;
var format1:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format1.color = 0x000000;
format.font = "Calibri";
format.size = 12;
txtDesc.defaultTextFormat = format1;
addChild(txtDesc);

function onCompleteXmlLoad(e:Event):void{

    xmlFile = new XML(xmlLoader.data);      

    var len:int = xmlFile.photo.length();

    txtTitle.text = xmlFile.photo.name[0];
    txtDesc.text = xmlFile.photo.desc[0];

    for(var i:int = 0;i<len;i++){
        var t:thumbs = new thumbs();
        t.x = xcoord;
        t.y = 10;
        t.buttonMode = true;        
        t.name = (i+1).toString();              
        thumbsContainer.addChild(t);

        t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseover);
        t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseout);
        t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);

        var tloader:Loader = new Loader();
        tloader.load(new URLRequest("thumbs/" + (i+1) + ".jpg"));
        t.addChild(tloader);        

        xcoord += t.width + 10;
    }

    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest("img/1.jpg"));
    gal.addChild(loader);


    scroller.source = thumbsContainer;
    scroller.setSize(550,110);

}

function onMouseover(e:MouseEvent):void{

    e.currentTarget.alpha = 0.5;

}

function onMouseout(e:MouseEvent):void{

    e.currentTarget.alpha = 1.0;

}


function onMouseClick(e:MouseEvent):void{

    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest("img/" + e.currentTarget.name + ".jpg"));    
    gal.addChild(loader);       

    txtTitle.text = xmlFile.photo.name[int(e.currentTarget.name) - 1];
    txtDesc.text = xmlFile.photo.desc[int(e.currentTarget.name) - 1];

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show us the `thumbs` class.

Comment: As said, this is a premade code so... I don't know where to find that thumbs class :\ The last code itself is working good without my flash project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within one of those two lines:

```
t.addChild(tloader);
```

or

```
gal.addChild(loader);
```

And the reason for this is because of `addChild is not a function` error message. If you were calling `addChild` on non-existing object, the error would be something else.

`t` is of type `thumbs` - `var t:thumbs = new thumbs();` and `gal` is `gallery` - `var gal:gallery = new gallery();`

So either one of those classes (`thumbs` or `gallery`) is problematic. They should do one of the following (inside the classes):

- extend `DisplayObjectContainer` - `Sprite` or even `MovieClip` are safest
- provide `addChild` kind of function

Comment: Hello and thank you for the reply, but in my first message I mentioned that the photo gallery only is working outside of my project. But when it is embedded into my project, I'm having that error. Could it be "somehow" having conflicts or something?

Comment: Well you are calling `addChild` method do the `gal` object. So if this method is missing, for sure it won't work :) And it can work separately, as no one is calling non existing methods.. My advise would be to see what is `gallery` extending and if it has method for adding images..